# How to define shipping rule?

Tags: magento2, shipping

I wants to made a shipping rule in which if a customer make order of below 3000/= flat charges 150 rupees apply must and if he's order amount is more than 3000 than it must be free shipping, so i make a rule in my extension which is given below:

[image]

There i define condition if subtotal is less than or equals to 3000, shipping method should be  flat rate apply, than i also enable free shipping method and set minimum order requirement to 3001,

But the problem is when user place more than 3000 order it shows both shipping methods, can any one guide me why? although i set not to show method if not applicable in flat rate  as well as in free shipping.

[image]

Comment: What is your Magento version? 1 or 2?

Comment: i am using magento2 , but the secreenshot above is from magento1 , sombody sent me i applied it same on my magento2